# iPad/iPhone duplicate view and resize?

Tags: iphone, ipad, vga

I'm working on an app that is similar to a Presentation application (Keynote/Powerpoint) for the iPad, that will use the VGA adapter to present on screen. However, if the presenter is using the external display for the presentation, I'm wondering if it's possible to have a miniature version of what's on the external display show up on the main iPad display (along with the presentation controls, which will take up most of the screen). In other words, I'm looking for a way with the iPhone SDK to "bake" the contents of a View (which will contain various Images and Labels in various locations) to an image (or some other static storage), resize it, and re-display it in another view.

It would need to be smaller (since I don't want the 1024x768 external display to completely overlay the iPad's main display, only a corner of it), and either live-updating (literally an instance of the other View, just scaled), or be able to be refreshed, such that when updating the external display, the "picture in picture" version of itself would be updated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to just have two instances of a view - one that is the full size on the external display and one that has its transform property set to fit in the preview window (and then update both simultaneously).

Otherwise you probably have to dive into Quartz and use the view's layer property to render it to a context (see CGBitmapContextCreate) and draw that onto a tiny view (this is all speculation of course).

Comment: I second this way. If you were to convert the view to an image you would loose all dynamic things that may happen on screen. Just make a 2nd instance and then apply a transform to scale it.

Comment: I had found the ways to adjust the frame of a view, but not the scale; I'll take a look at the Transform property and see if that gets me where I need.